# how to connect a html forms to a php associative variable

Tags: php, html, forms

i am trying to connect a form which will allow the user to enter in a country name and will return the correct capital. If the country is not in the list, display a message to the user to inform them that this country is not listed. The list of countries are stored in a PHP associative array. when i enter the first country it is returning the right capital, but when i enter any other country it returns this country is not listened. would anyone be able to tell me what is wrong with my code?
By the way sorry if the explanation of my problem is not clear. i am just learning web development now.

```php
<?php
    
    $coutries = array(
        "Italy" => "Rome", "Luxembourg" => "Luxembourg", "Belgium" => "Brussels",
        "Denmark" => "Copenhagen", "Finland" => "Helsinki", "France" => "Paris", "Slovakia" => "Bratislava",
        "Slovenia" => "Ljubljana", "Germany" => "Berlin", "Greece" => "Athens", "Ireland" => "Dublin",
        "Netherlands" => "Amsterdam", "Portugal" => "Lisbon", "Spain" => "Madrid", "Sweden" => "Stockholm",
        "United Kingdom" => "London", "Cyprus" => "Nicosia", "Lithuania" => "Vilnius", "Czech Republic" => "Prague",
        "Estonia" => "Tallin", "Hungary" => "Budapest", "Latvia" => "Riga", "Malta" => "Valetta", "Austria" => "Vienna",
        "Poland" => "Warsaw"
    );
    
    if(isset($_POST['notes'])){
        $query = $_POST['notes'];
        foreach($coutries as $key => $state){
            if($query == $key){
                echo $state;
            break;
            }else{
                echo "there is no match!";
            break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    ?>
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>Enter the country you would like to visit</label>
    <input type="text" name= "notes"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You don't need that foreach() loop. At least, I'd suggest https://www.php.net/isset or https://www.php.net/array_key_exists instead.

Comment: Have a closer look at your if code. See it? That else echoes "No match" and breaks right after the first foreach() iteration if it doesn't match! (Well, there's a break for the case when there *is* a match as well..) You can't say that there's no match until you've looped through all the options, right?

Comment: You mean that i should not have a break in the else echoes? i have tried without it and it gives me the output of no match, no match, no match...... and at last gives me the state. how could i fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code has `break;` in both cases, match/not match. So the foreach() loop always breaks/quits after the first iteration. When you think about it logically it does make more sense to hold off on saying "no match" until you've checked all the options, right ;)?

You could write the foreach like this:

```
$match = false;
foreach($coutries as $key => $state){
    if($query === $key){
        $match = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($match) {
    echo $state; // foreach index variables still exist here..
}
else {
    echo "No match!";
}
```

Or like this, using functions to check for a given key directly. Then you can skip the foreach() altogether:

```
if (array_key_exists($query, $coutries)) { // ..or isset($coutries[$query])
    echo $coutries[$query];
}
else {
    echo "No match!";
}
```

Comment: Thank you Torbjörn Stabo, it is working now and i could understand why it was not working the way i was doing.